# Making the most general lagrangian of triplet scalar fields under $SU(3)$ symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, renormalization

I need to write the most general renormalized lagrangian under those conditions:

1. The symmetry is global $SU(3)_G$
2. There is 3 triplets of scalar field $\phi(3)_i$ , $i=1,2,3$
3. There are no fermion fields.

I use Einstein`s notation
$\mathcal L=(\partial_{\mu}\phi_i)^2-m_i^2\phi^{\dagger}_{i}\phi_i-\eta(some- combination -of -three -fields)-\lambda_i( \phi^{\dagger}_{i}\phi_i)^2$

So as you can see in the lagrangian I don`t know how to build the trilinear term - I know it must be a singlet, but how do I create singlet out of 3 triplets? 
The second question is does there is more quadratic and quartic elements exist in the lagrangian then of how I wrote this?

Comment: Presumably in 4D?

Comment: Of course due to Lorentz invariance and Renormalizability

Comment: Is there any symmetry acting on the $i$ index? Do you consider redefinitions of the $\phi_i$? What about $\phi_1^\dagger \phi_2$?

Comment: And do you knwo how three coloured quarks form a colour-neutral proton?

Comment: quarks are fermions, in this question there is only scalars

Comment: That's just it: $3\times 3 \times 3$ contains a singlet, but it is antisymmetric, so it's good for fermions but not scalars (unless you give those a flavor permitting antisymmetrization...).

Comment: @CosmasZachos, could you please expand your comment into an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @MadMax I cannot, as the question is ambiguous: "3 triplets" insinuates a hidden global $SU(3)_c$ as well (global, since the derivatives are not color covariant), but without explicitly mentioning it, one is unsure of the OP's real intentions. Without it, he has 3x2 d.o.f., with it he has 3x3x2 d.o.f. , the 2 coming from complex conjugation.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I don't see the ambiguity here, doesn't the parenthesis in $\phi (3)$ imply that the scalar fields sits in the triplet representation and he says there are 3 triplets which means the system he is referring to has, as you mention $3\times 3\times 2$ dof.

Comment: @Sanjay M : It might be best if he himself said so...  are the indices *i* pertaining to $SU(3)_G$, or to each triplet? If not, should there be a symmetry, at all, w.r.t. them? If there is a global symmetry $SU(3)_G\times SU(3)_c$ why doesn't he say so, and only mentions only one SU(3) symmetry?

Comment: PS. If the indices *i* are not pertaining to the sole SU(3), so do not represent a symmetry, then *any* asymmetric jumble of them is allowed in SU(3)-invariant quartics, not just the symmetric one you worte. You *must* specify what you have in mind.

Comment: @CosmasZachos You're right! My answer would be true only if he specifies an additional $SU(3)$ flavour symmetry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah , it is a bit tricky to find the third order term. Essentially, it is pretty clear that we need use the epsilon tensor. Once you figure that out , it might seem that the antisymmetric tensor will give a zero term as mentioned by Cosmos Zachos , but we need to note that we have three different flavours in the model. Hence, we could have a term of the form , $$\epsilon^{abc}\phi_{1a}\phi_{2b}\phi_{3c}\sim \det[\Phi]$$ where the indices $a,b,c$ are the $SU(3)$ indices.

Note that this could only be done since we have at least 3 flavours. Also, if you want to give the most general renormalizable Lagrangian, you should in general allow varied coupling constants instead of a single $\lambda$ and also varied masses for the three flavours

Comment: What is $\Phi$ ?

Comment: It's the matrix with the three columns (or rows) being $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$